# Reactive value not updating based on dependent value

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, reactive, laravel-api

I have a project of Roles and Permission in Laravel API based with Vue.js frontend. In Add Roles page if clicking the "All" checkbox, all roles are checked but no data appears in `inputPermission.permissions`

```js
const permissions = ref([])
const inputPermissions = reactive({
  all: false,
  name: [],
  permissions:[],
})
async function getPermission() {
  await Axios.get(urlGenerator(PERMISSION)).then(res =>  {
    permissions.value = res.data.data
  }).catch(error => {
    console.log(error)
    return error;
  })
}
```

```html
<form class="mt-5">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Role<span class="text-danger px-1">*</span></label>
    <input
      type="text"
      name="name"
      v-model="inputPermissions.name"
      class="form-control"
      placeholder="Role name"
    />
    <small v-if="error.name" class="form-text font-size-12 text-danger">{{ error.name }}</small>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="per">Permission</label>

    <div class="form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        <input v-model="inputPermissions.all" type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" />
        All
      </label>
    </div>

    <hr />
    <div v-for="permission in permissions" :key="permission.id" class="pb-1 form-check">
      <label class="form-check-label">
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          v-model="inputPermissions.permissions"
          :checked="inputPermissions.all"
          class="form-check-input"
          :value="permission.name"
        />
        {{ permission.name }}
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button @click.prevent="saveRole" type="submit" class="btn btn-light btn-outline-dark">
    Save Role
  </button>
</form>
```

Comment: It's unclear how this `v-model="inputPermissions.permissions"` is supposed to work. It's an array. Probably should be `v-model="inputPermissions.permissions[index]"`? Then it likely should be assigned at some point, like the answer suggests. Also using value and v-model together doesn't make sense, check what v-model means in the docs

Answer (score 0):

The "All" checkbox has `v-model="inputPermissions.all"` so there is only two way binding between the input and this one property.  You need to create the side-effect of adding/removing all permissions based on the `all` value changing.  There are multiple ways to do it, but one way is with a [watcher](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/watchers.html).

When `inputPermissions.all` is true, add all permission names to `inputPermissions.permissions`.  When it becomes false, set an empty array.

```js
watch(
  () => inputPermissions.all,
  isChecked => {
    if (isChecked) {
      inputPermissions.permissions = permissions.value.map(v => v.name)
    } else {
      inputPermissions.permissions = []
    }
  }
)
```

[Vue Playground example](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)